# Relative Path com subdiretório virtual

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Boa tarde,

Estive procurando na internet por soluções para este meu atual problema com paths, porém não consigo encontrar.

Imaginem que tenho os seguintes links:

> www.site/Arquivos/Uploads/imagem.png
>
> www.sitedev/Cliente/Arquivos/Uploads/imagem.png

Neste caso, no primeiro link consigo sempre pegar sem problemas o path da imagem por back-end utilizando `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`, porém quando tento o mesmo com o segundo link, ele ignora a subpasta Cliente. No caso, eu passo como parâmetro "~/Arquivos/Uploads/imagem.png".

Esta subpasta existe em um ambiente de desenvolvimento para que seja hospedado diferentes aplicações.

Existe algum método que consiga pegar ambos os casos, ou até mesmo com mais subdiretórios antes de onde a aplicação se encontra?

---

**Edição**

---

Um dos casos que estou com problemas é com o código a seguir:

```
// Os valores das variáveis são:
//
// ultimoDigitoDoId = "4";
// Configuracoes.DiretorioUploadEmpresa = "~/Arquivos/uploads/empresas/"

var pasta = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(String.Format("{0}{1}\\{2}",
    Configuracoes.DiretorioUploadEmpresa, 
    ultimoDigitoDoId, 
    "Imagens"));

if (!Directory.Exists(pasta))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(pasta)
```

Quando o a pasta é criada e os arquivos são salvos nela, ela é criada fora do contexto 'Cliente', aquele que mostrei acima nos dois exemplos de link

Comment: Mostre como está usando.

Comment: Você tem um ClienteController?

Comment: Precisamos de uma amostra do código que realiza o mapeamento. `Server.MapPath` é uma opção, mas existem outras.

Comment: @AndreMesquita Não, pasta e imagens são salvas com o código que inseri na edição

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez postei uma amostra

Comment: @bigown Fiz uma edição na minha postagem. Acredito que o problema principal é a criação da pasta, pois com essa mesma pasta criada (em local errado), ele salva as imagens dentro dela utilizando essa mesma variável como referência.

Comment: @striterAlfa você tem um controlador chamado ClienteController? Se tiver, quando você tentar gravar o arquivo nessa pasta, será que não está sendo chamada uma action de nome Arquivos?

Comment: @AndreMesquita busquei na solution o nome ClienteController e não obtive resultados. O problema, como comentei na resposta do Cigano logo abaixo, é que "Cliente" não é um diretório fixo, ele varia de acordo com o IIS em que a aplicação está rodando. Existe ambientes de homologação que ele se chama "Homolog" E de desenvolvimento que ele se chama "Dev". Consigo pegar essa informação pelo javascript usando window.baseUrl, mas não consigo pegá-la no backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tem problema algum com o seu código. É apenas uma questão da lógica envolvida:

```
var pasta = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(String.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}\\{3}",
    "Cliente",
    Configuracoes.DiretorioUploadEmpresa, 
    ultimoDigitoDoId, 
    "Imagens"));
```

Comment: A questão, Cigano, é que eu não poderia colocar "Cliente" fixo no código. Ele é utilizado para vários clientes diferente, e em determinados ambientes de testes esse nome muda de acordo com a pasta em que o projeto se encontra rodando no IIS. Se ele estiver dentro de uma pasta Homolog, por exemplo, ele tewntaria pegar em uma pasta chamada Cliente, de novo, cairia no problema de criar a pasta e salvar as informações em local errado

Comment: Isso se resolve com configuração e lógica. Use `<appConfig>` para especificar o nome do cliente, ou ambiente, ou a convenção que quiser para formatar o nome do diretório. Fora isso, está tudo certo.